# Indexes on Array of Object fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Suppose I have the following schema

```
//LevelColor

{
   "Colors" : [
        {
            "Color" : "Red", "Code" : "#FF0000"
        },
        {
            "Color" : "Black", "Code" : "#000000"
        },
        {
            "Color" : "White", "Code" : "#FFFFFF"
        }
   ]
}
```

And I have index on it

```
{"Colors.Color" : 1}
```

But for some specific reason, I need to query for the first element only, like

```
{"Colors.0.Color" : "Red"}
```

In above query index not being utilized but for below query it is being utilized

```
{"Colors.Color" : "Red"}
```

But I need for query first element, Any alternative way to query on the first element or can I  optimize index to utilize in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

To support that first-element query with an index, you would have to create an index on just the first element of `Colors`, by creating an index on:

```js
{"Colors.0.Color" : 1}
```

Comment: But this will support only first element, is there any way to support both queries in a single index?

Comment: Not that I can see. You'd need an index over the `Color` field and its position in the `Colors` array, which isn't supported. Another way to approach this would be to include whatever first-element meaning you have as another property of the `Colors` array element so that you _could_ index it.